# Can't install or update redhat-lsb package for RHEL 5

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel, rhel5, lsb

I moved a daemon shell-script from a Devian server to a RHEL 5 server. The script now throws the error :

```
E: /lib/lsb/init-functions not found, lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) needed
```

The error in the script seems to come from here:

```
if ! [ -x "/lib/lsb/init-functions" ]; then
        . /lib/lsb/init-functions
else
        echo "E: /lib/lsb/init-functions not found, lsb-base (>= 3.0-6) needed"
        exit 1
fi
```

But when I try to install a newer version of the lsb-base for RHEL5 I get the following:

```
[root@********** tmp]# rpm -ivh redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386.rpm
warning: redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID 192a7d7d
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        file /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_start_daemon from install of redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz from install of redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64
        file /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_start_daemon from install of redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386
        file /usr/sbin/redhat_lsb_trigger.i386 from install of redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386
        file /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz from install of redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386
```

When I try to upgrade it with the same version *redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386.rpm* or *redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64.rpm* I get that:

```
>> rpm -Uvh redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64.rpm
>> warning: redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64.rpm: Header V3 DSA signature: NOKEY, key ID a7048f8d
Preparing...                ########################################### [100%]
        package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64 is already installed
        file /usr/sbin/redhat_lsb_trigger.x86_64 from install of redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz from install of redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64
        file /usr/share/man/man1/lsb_release.1.gz from install of redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64 conflicts with file from package redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386
```

Information about the system:

```
[root@*********** tmp]# cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-128.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc1-7.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44)) #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 11:41:38 EST 2008
[root@*********** tmp]# cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 5.3 (Tikanga)
```

EDIT:
There is no yum installed, that's why I didn't tried to install it via that.
Any idea?

Same problem occurs for the following packages:

- redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.i386.rpm
- redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.src.rpm
- redhat-lsb-3.1-12.3.EL.x86_64.rpm
- redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.i386.rpm
- redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.src.rpm
- redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to install an RPM for the i386 architecture but your system is x86_64. Try installing [redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.x86_64.rpm](ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/5.10/os/x86_64/CentOS/redhat-lsb-4.0-2.1.4.el5.x86_64.rpm)

Comment: Sorry my original post wasn't clear enough. Yes, I also tried it with that package you said, but sadly I get the same error! Thanks for your help, though!

Answer (score 0):

Use following Parameters the RPMs :

`- F` Force to install packege

`--replacepkgs` : Install the packages even if some of them are already installed on this system.

`--nodeps`: Don't do a dependency check before installing or upgrading a package

Using this command resolve this type of errors: